# IO.StringWriter can be used to copy any control data into Excel ? (Previously I have used IO.StringWriter for copying Gridview data into Excel)

Tags: vb.net, excel, gridview

Below code is used to copy Gridview data into excel

```
Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim htw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)

' Render grid view control.
gvradio.RenderControl(htw)

' Write the rendered content to a file.
Dim renderedGridView As String = sw.ToString()

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Rashu\Desktop\ExportedFile.xls", renderedGridView)
```

Comment: May i know your problem?

Comment: I want to copy all controls text into excel. Like over my Button control I put Text "Click me" ,In Lable "Information Below is correct" and in html table data is displaying .

Comment: Have you tried it?  In the amount of time it took to post the question and wait for an answer (1 hour as of this comment) you probably could have tested it yourself. :)

Comment: yup Now I tested ...now I am able to fetch the <div></div> tag data into excel :)yeeahhh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loop through all control and take their text value, some thing like this :

```
 Dim s As System.Text.StringBuilder
 For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
       s.AppendLine(cntrl.Text)
 Next
```

Comment: Hey I want to display all along with other data in Excel.:) without using any third party dll .

Comment: 4 button text that is one div tag and gridview data into excel.

Comment: my code will give all control text added to text you had from gridview 

use it like that :

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Rashu\Desktop\ExportedFile.xls", renderedGridView & s.ToString)`

Comment: Hey Thanks I have test its works. But I want to add a new row in excel file with this how can I add a blank row? like "\n" works well in .txt file.